# Is re-meet a correct way to say meet again

Tags: meaning

I haven’t really hear someone said remeet and ive never use it so is it an actual word or what other ways are there to say meet again.

Comment: Re-meet is bad. See you soon. Until the next time. In French, *au revoir*.

Answer (score 3):

Although it makes sense, "re-meet" is not an idiomatic English phrase.  Instead you would say "Let's meet again" or "Let's get together again" or a similar phrase:

> I hope we **see each other again** soon!

You can, however, *get reacquainted* with someone who you previously knew, but haven't seen for a while.

> After he got back, he spent some time **getting reacquainted** with his neighbors, who he hadn't spoken to since before he went off to war.

Answer (score 1):

No, "re-meet" is not idiomatic English.

If the intended meaning of "meet" is not "encounter for the first time", but the equally common "have a meeting with", and you are trying to express the idea of gathering again for another meeting, the word you are looking for is "reconvene".  Example:

> With a bitter election campaign finally over, the U.S. Congress will reconvene this week to try to set aside its partisan differences long enough to keep the government from closing.

Answer (score 0):

Meet has several connotations. It can simply mean to get together, but it also means "encounter someone for the first time." It can even mean "be formally introduced to someone."

Because the latter two meanings are something that can typically happen only once, I believe they are what prevent "meet" from taking the prefix *re-*.

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, ***re-encounter*** has no such hang-up. It does seem to be a verb in English (UK) and a noun in English (Simplified) though.